# Interacting with a PDF popup in Selenium 2

Tags: selenium, pdf, selenium-webdriver, testing

I'm trying to test a page where clicking a button generates a popup that's in PDF form.
I'd like selenium to click on the popup and either take a screenshot of the screen or save the PDF.

I use the following code to get all the window handles to use the `switchTo()` command, but when I execute it it only returns a single window. Selenium doesn't seem to recognize the PDF popup.

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
//converts set to array
String[] array = handles.toArray(new String[0]);

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Is there another way to switchTo the PDF popup?

Comment: I gave you a start below.  But I don't have quite enough information to answer you 100% and get my answer marked as "The Answer" unless you're generous.  (1) Is the PDF being launched in an HTTP Handler (as the file itself) OR (2) in an object--strict (or iFrame--transitional) tag with the PDF streamed to that page that's launched inside the object/iFrame like in PDFViewer.aspx OR (3), is it being launched in its own page (like the PDFViewer.aspx)?  That will make a big difference in the solution to the task at hand here.

Comment: Are you saying that the PDF opens in Adobe application rather than in the browser PDF plugin?  If so, maybe its just a mime-type adjustment to get the PDF to open in a 2nd browser window, then you can use WebDriver window handles methods to track both windows and screenshot it (perhaps using Sikuli?).

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894071/chromedriver-selenium-automate-downloads

Answer (score 2):

Because Selenium can only control things that the DOM can control (the IDE is just running JavaScript) you cannot take a screen shot.  Your only option is to save it, unless JavaScript for the new HTML5 is that powerful to launch things on the Operating System (I don't know).  I will let you find the code to save a PDF on Google using JavaScript, but this information should get you started.  Just create a custom command, called Selenium.prototype.doLaunchAndSavePDF or something, to launch your PDF and save it.  And have your "target" parameter be the path and name of the file.  I'm not sure how Selenium passes the forward (or backward) slashes to JavaScript, so be careful of that.  Good luck!

**Option #1 - if using Selenium IDE:**

Specify the user-extensions.js file under Selenium IDE > Options (menu) > Options (menu option) > General Tab, then browse to your file under "Selenium Core Extensions".

**Option #2 - if using Selenium RC Server:**

If you're not using the IDE and using Selenium RC server with a client driver (like JUnit for example), you must specify the path of the *.js file with the -userExtensions parameter when you start the Selenium RC Server on the command line. But you said you just wanted to use the IDE, so I'd ignore this. It takes quite a bit of other setup to use the Selenium RC server.

java -jar selenium-server.jar -userExtensions user-extensions.js

=======================

I made the following custom command (JavaScript function) in my custom user-extensions.js file.. I had to exit and restart the IDE before it found it.  Type everything after the "do" in the "Command" field in the IDE to find the custom command. It looks like it also added a "customAlertAndWait" to the IDE as well.

**Code in user-extensions.js file:**

Selenium.prototype.doCustomAlert = function(sTarget, sValue) { alert('Target: ' + sTarget + ' ... Value: ' + sValue); };

**Selenium IDE command details:**

Command: customAlert
Target: custom alert target
Value: custom alert value