# How to save embedded PDF opened in Chrome from Python Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The ChromeDriver for Selenium was able to open an embedded PDF after login, but how can I save the PDF file in chrome to local disk? thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You're likely to get a better response to your question if you post some code that shows what you've tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I managed to achieve the task by disable chrome pdf viewer and let the chrome browser directly download the pdf file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chromedriver, Selenium - Automate downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894071/chromedriver-selenium-automate-downloads)

Answer (score 10):

```
def download_pdf(lnk):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    tgt = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
        "download.default_directory" : tgt}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs",profile)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER, chrome_options = options)
    driver.get(lnk)
    driver.find_element_by_id('userName1').send_keys('username')
    driver.find_element_by_id('password1').send_keys('password')
    driver.find_element_by_id('loginButton1').click()

    ftgt = os.path.join(tgt,'downloaed.pdf')
    while not os.path.exists(ftgt):
        time.sleep(3)
    driver.close()
    return ftgt
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to use tempfile? And why to wait for os.path.exists?