# Save as pdf in selenium using Phantomjs in java

Tags: java, selenium, pdf, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I want to perform some tasks using selenium in java

```
//java code
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.get("http://www.example.com");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));  
element.sendKeys("Guru99");                 
element.submit();
```

After Submitting the form I want to save the result page as pdf.
How can i achieve this. 
I don't know anything about other programming languages,so please help using java code.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I don't know anything about python,if you could help me with java code that would be great

Comment: Oops- my bad, pls ignore the comment and closing vote!

Comment: @DanCornilescu No problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chromedriver, Selenium - Automate downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894071/chromedriver-selenium-automate-downloads)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do to achieve your result:-

Once you navigate to your result page after submitting the `text` you need to get the `source` of the page using:-

```
String htmlFileContent = driver.getPageSource();
```

Then you can create a file with this `html` content something like:-

```
File file = new File("index.html");
file.createNewFile();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("index.html", "UTF-8");
pw.print(htmlFileContent);
```

Once the content is written in `HTML` file. You can use iText Library or any other pdf converter library to convert your `html` into `pdf`

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I will try and tell back

Comment: text inside output pdf is not arranged properly

Comment: ok in this case what you can do is just take a screenshot of that page in `png` or `jpeg` and convert that into `pdf`.

Comment: I want the pdf to be searchable

Comment: There is one service that I know but its not open source. You can use that api call and pass the exact url and it directly converts your `html` to `pdf`.

Comment: In my case,I have to perform some query on a page,and the result after performing query,i want to save it as pdf,so passing url won't work.