# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'. Getting this error when running a python Script on Appium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, appium

```
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy

capabilities = dict(
    platformName='Android',
    automationName='uiautomator2',
    deviceName='Samsung S9',
    appPackage='com.android.settings',
    appActivity='.Settings',
    language='en',
    locale='US'
)

appium_server_url = 'http://localhost:4723'

class TestAppium(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, capabilities)

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        if self.driver:
            self.driver.quit()

    def test_find_battery(self) -> None:
        el = self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value='//*[@text="Battery"]')
        el.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The above is the example code from official Appium website (http://appium.io/docs/en/2.1/quickstart/test-py/), I have installed all the prequisites requred but still I'm getting the below error when I run the python file:

```
C:\Users\syeda\Desktop>python test.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_find_battery (__main__.TestAppium.test_find_battery)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\syeda\Desktop\test.py", line 19, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, capabilities)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\syeda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 229, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\syeda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in __init__
    capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I made sure the Appium server is running.

I'm not sure why this eroor is occuring. I tried searching on the web but no luck.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075624/how-to-add-selenium-chrome-options-to-desiredcapabilities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy

# Import Appium UiAutomator2 driver for Android platforms (AppiumOptions)
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options

capabilities = dict(
    platformName='Android',
    automationName='uiautomator2',
    deviceName='Samsung S9',
    appPackage='com.android.settings',
    appActivity='.Settings',
    language='en',
    locale='US'
)

appium_server_url = 'http://localhost:4723'

# Converts capabilities to AppiumOptions instance
capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(capabilities)

class TestAppium(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=appium_server_url,options=capabilities_options)

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        if self.driver:
            self.driver.quit()

    def test_find_battery(self) -> None:
        el = self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value='//*[@text="Battery"]')
        el.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: I gave more details on the comments in the code I sent back.
Please read it and give me some feedback

Comment: My feedback is that the answer would be better if the explanation of the changes you did was written as normal text outside the code.

Comment: Oh okay, I see.
Let me copy/paste it here:

# Import Appium UiAutomator2 driver for Android platforms (AppiumOptions)
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options

# Converts capabilities to AppiumOptions instance
capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(capabilities)

# Use the capabilities_options variable to load the application
class TestAppium(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=appium_server_url,options=capabilities_options)

I hope this can help you :)

Comment: @nelsound90 how can I fix this issue for iOS test?

Comment: This is not an useful answer, it's just a code snippet. Please clarify.

Comment: You have to add an Uiautomator2 instance and load the capabilities options.
The new version of appium requires capabilities options.

# Import Appium UiAutomator2 driver for Android platforms (AppiumOptions)
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options

# Import Appium XCUITestOptions driver is for ios if needed
from appium.options.ios import XCUITestOptions

Create the instance and convert the capabilities to capabilities options 

# Converts capabilities to AppiumOptions instance
capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(capabilities)

Comment: Then I've modified a bit the code used to call the capabilites options instance created

class TestAppium(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=appium_server_url,options=capabilities_options)

Answer (score 0):

In My case I update Appium-Python-Client. So I downgrade the python version.

```
pip install Appium-Python-Client==2.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this error with Appium-Python-Client 3.1.1 by adding the following code

```
from appium.options.common import AppiumOptions
driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, 
    options=AppiumOptions().load_capabilities(capabilities))
```

The AppiumOptions instance provides the load_capabilities() method that the original code is complaining about on line 185, in `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

For me, this solution is working

```
from appium.webdriver.webdriver import AppiumOptions

appium_options = AppiumOptions()
appium_options.load_capabilities(capabilities)
driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, options=appium_options)
```