# Selenium Webdriver - Help for PDF to text conversion

Tags: java, pdf, selenium-webdriver

Following code is perfectly downloading the PDF. Now I want to convert this PDF content to Text file.Please help. I tried with a lot many codes by goggling but none of them worked.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 @Test

 public class PDF_Download_without_popup {
 WebDriver driver;

 @BeforeTest
 public void StartBrowser() {

  //Create object of FirefoxProfile in built class to access Its properties.

  FirefoxProfile fprofile = new FirefoxProfile();

   //Set Location to store files after downloading.

  fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "c:\\WebDriverdownloads");

  fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);

//Set Preference to not show file download confirmation dialogue using MIME types Of different file extension types.

  fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;"//MIME types Of MS Excel File.
    + "application/pdf;" //MIME types Of PDF File.
    + "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;" //MIME types Of MS doc File.
    + "text/plain;" //MIME types Of text File.
    + "text/csv"); //MIME types Of CSV File.
  fprofile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );

  fprofile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );

  //Pass fprofile parameter In webdriver to use preferences to download file.

  driver = new FirefoxDriver(fprofile);  

 }  

  public void OpenURL() throws InterruptedException{

     driver.get("http://www.bell.ca/");
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     Thread.sleep(30000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='demoLoginLinkJs']/span[1]")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='USER']")).sendKeys("bell_56789");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PASSWORD']")).sendKeys("sunday21");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='demoLoginJs']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'View current bill')]")).click();

     Thread.sleep(5000);


     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnDownloadBill']")).click();
     String tmp= driver.getCurrentUrl().toString();
     System.out.println(tmp);
     Thread.sleep(50000);


 }

 @AfterTest
 public void CloseBrowser() {  
  driver.quit();   
 }
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Please share the code or link for converting the PDF to Text after downloading the PDF from Selenium webdriver

Comment: the java code is not processing the PDF to Text.. please help

Comment: I think it is not possible as text can not set PDF formatting, what you can do is can convert pdf to rich text file format using java I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the [Apache PDFBox API](https://pdfbox.apache.org).

Then add it to your project.

In your case you are downloading the PDF, but don't download it, give the URL in `navigate.to()` to open the PDF in the browser, e.g.: http://www.bell.ca/xyz.pdf.
So, your code will be something like:

```
URL xyzUrl = new URL("http://www.bell.ca/xyz.pdf");

BufferedInputStream TestFile = new BufferedInputStream(xyzUrl.openStream());
PDDocument xyzPDF = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(TestFile, null);
String testText = new PDFTextStripper().getText(xyzPDF);
xyzPDF.close();
```

Now you have fetched all text from the PDF file and can write those texts into an external XLS or any relevant type file using a third party API like Apache POI or any other available APIs.

Comment: Hi Pritam,i tried before with code you have shared. The problem here is , in my application URL is PDF download source page: https://mybell.bell.ca/Mobility/Billing/CurrentMobilityBill?AcctNo=506540566207DA7D21817764E2831250CF419BC141B457EAE761A07E862087A1B6D26EF365972B6F

Comment: The pdf is opening as a native windows app/through browser plugin and selenium can't handle that If this is the case then, after downloading, the pdf file will no longer under a browser, and selenium can't automate it as pdf will be a native window application after download.:(. It may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668141/interacting-with-a-pdf-popup-in-selenium

Comment: I edited your answer (which is OK) so that it uses the current PDFBox API.

Answer (score 0):

> @Geetanjali, I can suggest another way around.  There are several
>   online website who provide pdf to text conversion service. There you
>   just need to upload your file and click "convert", then your pdf will 
>   be converted to text.
>
> So, my point is you can automate it also every time you download a
>   pdf. After downloading the pdf, open one of those websites. Upload
>   your file using third party tool like AutoIT API (add in your buildpath).
>   and can download the text file after conversion.